# Debugging High CPU Usage From CSS

Tags: html, performance, css

I'm trying to debug a web app that is consistently using 13-15% CPU at idle. I've determined that my stylesheet is the culprit. Removing it drops idle CPU usage to 0.1% in Chrome. Unfortunately my stylesheet is thousands of lines long, so going through line-by-line isn't an option. I've seen numerous posts and blog articles on this issue, many of which suggest using `will-change: transform` and/or `transform: translateZ(0)` in conjunction with the `transform` property. I've already applied this rule throughout my CSS, and it has only saved me about 2% CPU usage.

I've been attempting to debug the issue with Chrome Dev Tools but have made limited progress. From what I can tell using the Timeline tab, the app spends a lot of time at idle `Painting` and `Rendering` the canvas. See attached screenshot.

[image]

What I would like to know is if there is a comprehensive list of CSS properties that are known CPU hogs, and strategies for addressing them. Animations seem like an obvious culprit, however my app has almost none.

A few notes about my CSS:

- My app does not make use of the CSS3 `animate` property at all.
- It makes extensive use of the `background-image` and associated
  positioning properties (`background-size`, `background-position`,
  etc), which based on my profiling, seem to account for around 6-7% of
  idle CPU usage.
- The app has about half a dozen jQuery animations, however those
  seemed to only raise CPU usage briefly when triggered, which would be
  expected.
- The app relies fairly heavily on the use of absolute/fixed
  positioning and associated properties (e.g. `top`, `left`, etc).
- The app relies on `box-shadow` and `text-shadow` properties quite a
  bit.
- My stack is Angular 1.5, Angular UI Bootstrap 1.3.2, jQuery 2, Bootstrap 3, and Font Awesome

For reference, [here is a gist of my custom CSS](https://gist.github.com/danielbonnell/cc8cf4171b971ff199b0a2614e64134d), which overrides Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I think you've identified a lot of them,,,if the browswer is animating boxes with shadows it has to do a lot of re-painting for each px change between positions. Does the CPU usage drop if you turn off the shadows?

Comment: Frankly, though, this is so broad and untestable (by us) I'm not sure that this is a good fit for Stack Overflow. Perhaps another part of the Stack Exchange family might be better.

Comment: Removing all `box-shadow` and `text-shadow` properties globally had no effect. I first tried using the `*` selector and `!important` to disable them globally and also just commenting out every property in the file, either way had almost no effect on CPU usage.

Comment: You might apply a "divide and conquer" approach to the CSS file.